# How Cursor Batches Works in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to `mongodb`,when i was going through  [cursor batches](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-batches) it tells the amount of data in the batch will not exceed the maximum `BSON` document size,but when i go through [Bson Document Size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size) it tells The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes,i can't get whether the batch will be of size `16 megabytes` or each document in batch will `16 megabytes`, how does cursor batch works if my query returns `20 documents` whose  minimum size  `1mb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query looking for documents what `mongodb` does is it just return the cursor of selected documents,but returning cursor alone is not efficient so we can fetch first batch of results which also add overhead if result set is too large. So, as a compromise and to improve performance what `mongodb` does is return the first 101 documents in the initial batch wait for next cursor call after subsequent requests cursors dont have the default size so that it limits to 16mb message size!!!